# How to make "sourceDirectories" public in Jacoco report generation?

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco, test-coverage

I was following [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/generate-global-code-coverage-report-in-android-development-using-jacoco-plugin) post to setup Jacoco code coverage for my project.

But I am facing a error while writing the task to generate the report.

#### Gradle Task

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/**/*.ec'
    ])
}
```

The error I am getting is :

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'sourceDirectories' for
> task ':app:jacocoTestReport' of type
> org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.

Below field's are private in the `jacoco` now I believe.

- sourceDirectories
- classDirectories
- executionData

My dependency : `classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.4"`

Also, I tried to change the version but no help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the Answer [here](https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin/issues/83#issuecomment-647383772)

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from files([debugTree])
    executionData.from fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/**/*.ec'
    ])
}
```

> (sourceDirectories =) in not allowed in latest gradle version instead (sourceDirectories.from) should be used .